# Xcode version control system for parent project with several children

Tags: iphone, xcode, version-control

I need some advice about working with Xcode and a version control system - I guess either SVN or git. It's a solo project, so local repository is fine

I have a main Xcode project, that also needs to be forked into a number of very similar, but slightly different projects, that all need to be built separately. Since the easy approach of having x separate Xcode projects it not particularly space-efficient, or user friendly, I investigated how to do this with version control.

The idea is that everything should be accessible from one project. Whenever you want to change the version being worked on, you checkout a new copy from the version control, which changes the existing project to match that new version. In addition you should be able to update something in the main version which also updates (or makes it easy to update) the child versions. The build settings should also be independent for each project.

My first attempts with SVN were not particularly successful. I found that I was just keeping different working copies for each branch. When I tried to change the project to another branch and update the working copy (either within or out of Xcode), I just managed to corrupt things. And I also found that history was only enabled for versions created within that trunk, whereas I wanted to see the history of all changes.

Presumably this sort of situation is quite common - I thought there would be a way to work with it in Xcode? Does anyone have any tips for the best way to efficiently maintain a project with a core trunk, but several minor branches. I assumed this is one of the situations the VCS are built for, perhaps I'm just not using them right.

Dummies guide to VCS anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to user [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).

It is easy to work with, Mercurial is a free, distributed source control management tool. It efficiently handles projects of any size and offers an easy and intuitive interface

Comment: well thanks, but that's not really the question. Can it do what I say I need above?

Comment: yes, mercurial satisfy your requirement. It allows distributed version control. you can active what is required. go through the docs of mercurial